# activemq stateful set kubernetes pods failing to start

Tags: docker, kubernetes, activemq-classic, kubernetes-statefulset

I have this weird error plaguing me.

I am trying to get an activemq pod running with a kubernetes stateful set, volume attached.

The activemq is just a plain old vanila docker image, picked it from here https://hub.docker.com/r/rmohr/activemq/

```
INFO | Refreshing org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1@3fee9989: startup date [Thu Aug 23 22:12:07 GMT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
 INFO | Using Persistence Adapter: KahaDBPersistenceAdapter[/opt/activemq/data/kahadb]
 INFO | KahaDB is version 6
 INFO | PListStore:[/opt/activemq/data/localhost/tmp_storage] started
 INFO | Apache ActiveMQ 5.15.4 (localhost, ID:activemq-0-43279-1535062328969-0:1) is starting
 INFO | Listening for connections at: tcp://activemq-0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600
 INFO | Connector openwire started
 INFO | Listening for connections at: amqp://activemq-0:5672?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600
 INFO | Connector amqp started
 INFO | Listening for connections at: stomp://activemq-0:61613?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600
 INFO | Connector stomp started
 INFO | Listening for connections at: mqtt://activemq-0:1883?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600
 INFO | Connector mqtt started
 WARN | ServletContext@o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@65a15628{/,null,STARTING} has uncovered http methods for path: /
 INFO | Listening for connections at ws://activemq-0:61614?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600
 INFO | Connector ws started
 INFO | Apache ActiveMQ 5.15.4 (localhost, ID:activemq-0-43279-1535062328969-0:1) started
 INFO | For help or more information please see: http://activemq.apache.org
 WARN | Store limit is 102400 mb (current store usage is 6 mb). The data directory: /opt/activemq/data/kahadb only has 95468 mb of usable space. - resetting to maximum available disk space: 95468 mb
 WARN | Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@478ee483{/admin,file:/opt/apache-activemq-5.15.4/webapps/admin/,null}
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Parent for temp dir not configured correctly: writeable=false
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration.makeTempDirectory(WebInfConfiguration.java:336)[jetty-all-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration.resolveTempDirectory(WebInfConfiguration.java:304)[jetty-all-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration.preConfigure(WebInfConfiguration.java:69)[jetty-all-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.preConfigure(WebAppContext.java:468)[jetty-all-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:504)[jetty-all-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)[jetty-all-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)[jetty-all-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)[jetty-all-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)[jetty-all-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)[jetty-all-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)[jetty-all-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)[jetty-all-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)[jetty-all-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.doStart(SecurityHandler.java:391)[jetty-all-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler.doStart(ConstraintSecurityHandler.java:449)[jetty-all-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)[jetty-all-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)[jetty-all-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)[jetty-all-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)[jetty-all-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)[jetty-all-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)[jetty-all-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:387)[jetty-all-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)[jetty-all-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)[jetty-all-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:354)[jetty-all-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)[jetty-all-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.8.0_171]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)[:1.8.0_171]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.8.0_171]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)[:1.8.0_171]
        at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:265)[spring-core-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingBean.invokeWithTargetException(MethodInvokingBean.java:119)[spring-beans-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(MethodInvokingFactoryBean.java:106)[spring-beans-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1692)[spring-beans-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1630)[spring-beans-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)[spring-beans-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)[spring-beans-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)[spring-beans-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)[spring-beans-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)[spring-beans-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)[spring-beans-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:742)[spring-beans-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)[spring-context-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)[spring-context-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:64)[xbean-spring-4.2.jar:4.2]
        at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:52)[xbean-spring-4.2.jar:4.2]
        at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1.<init>(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:104)[activemq-spring-5.15.4.jar:5.15.4]
        at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory.createApplicationContext(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:104)[activemq-spring-5.15.4.jar:5.15.4]
        at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory.createBroker(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:67)[activemq-spring-5.15.4.jar:5.15.4]
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(BrokerFactory.java:71)[activemq-broker-5.15.4.jar:5.15.4]
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(BrokerFactory.java:54)[activemq-broker-5.15.4.jar:5.15.4]
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.StartCommand.runTask(StartCommand.java:87)[activemq-console-5.15.4.jar:5.15.4]
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:63)[activemq-console-5.15.4.jar:5.15.4]
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.runTask(ShellCommand.java:154)[activemq-console-5.15.4.jar:5.15.4]
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:63)[activemq-console-5.15.4.jar:5.15.4]
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.main(ShellCommand.java:104)[activemq-console-5.15.4.jar:5.15.4]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.8.0_171]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)[:1.8.0_171]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.8.0_171]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)[:1.8.0_171]
        at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.runTaskClass(Main.java:262)[activemq.jar:5.15.4]
        at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.main(Main.java:115)[activemq.jar:5.15.4]
```

The kubernete activemq pod is running fine if we don't define it with stateful sets.

Below is the spec

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: activemq
  namespace: dev
  labels:
    app: activemq
spec:
  replicas: 1
  serviceName: activemq-svc
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: activemq
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: activemq
    spec:
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 1000
        fsGroup: 2000
        runAsNonRoot: false
      containers:
       - name: activemq
         image: "mydocker/amq:latest"
         imagePullPolicy: "Always"
         ports:
          - containerPort: 61616
            name: port-61616
          - containerPort: 8161
            name: port-8161
         volumeMounts:
          - name: activemq-data
            mountPath: "/opt/activemq/data"
      restartPolicy: Always
      imagePullSecrets:
       - name: regsecret
      tolerations:
        - effect: NoExecute
          key: appstype
          operator: Equal
          value: ibd-mq
      affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
            - matchExpressions:
              - key: appstype
                operator: In
                values:
                - dev-mq

  volumeClaimTemplates:
   - metadata:
       name: activemq-data
     spec:
       accessModes:
        - ReadWriteOnce
       storageClassName: "gp2-us-east-2a"
       resources:
         requests:
           storage: 100Gi
```

Comment: What is this image: `"mydocker/amq:latest"` -- or rather: what changes did you make to the upstream image and what was the upstream image tag? (BTW, using `:latest` is _bad news_)

Comment: Separately, while it absolutely won't affect the _functionality_, it is a poor practice to name a port `name: port-8161` since any observer can readily tell what the numeric port is, but would **not** be able to readily tell that 8161 is `activemq-ui` nor that 61616 is `activemq-tcp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> WARN | Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@478ee483{/admin,file:/opt/apache-activemq-5.15.4/webapps/admin/,null}
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Parent for temp dir not configured correctly: writeable=false

Unless you altered the `activemq` userid in your image, then that filesystem permission issue is caused by this stanza in your `PodSpec`:

```
spec:
  securityContext:
    runAsUser: 1000
    fsGroup: 2000
    runAsNonRoot: false
```

failing to match up with the userid configuration in `rmohr/activemq:5.15.4`:

```
$ docker run -it --entrypoint=/bin/bash rmohr/activemq:5.15.4 -c 'id -a'
uid=999(activemq) gid=999(activemq) groups=999(activemq)
```

Comment: Thank you! your answer led us to the real problem!